# Django "./manage.py bower install" tells me bower isn't installed when it is

Tags: python, django, pip, bower

I'm following the instructions from the django-bower setup readme [here](https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower). I've installed django-bower (v5.1.0) via `$ pip install -r requirements.txt` (django-bower==5.1.0 is in my requirements.txt). Now I'm trying to run `$ ./manage.py bower install` (as per the instructions) but I'm getting this error:

> BowerNotInstalled: Bower not installed, read instruction here - http://bower.io/

Trying to run `$ pip install django-bower` gives me a `Requirement already satisfied` message.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you add it to your installed apps ?

Comment: yep, I followed all of the instructions as they appear in the README

Comment: Did you install bower globally ? if not, did you set the path to where you installed bower ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error message indicates that `bower` cannot be found. `django-bower` is properly installed.

Check the instructions here: https://bower.io/#install-bower:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Comment: Ugh that was it. Cloned my repo to a machine that didn't have bower installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with this, and I did have bower installed.

This solved it for me (placed in **settings.py**)

```
import os

BOWER_PATH = os.path.normpath(r'/Users/username/.npm/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower')
```

(instead of 'username', put in your username ;) )

Copied from an answer I found that had slashes going the other way, I'm assuming from Windows, so here's the example with that:

```
BOWER_PATH = os.path.normpath(r'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd')
```